# Find text which is part of cell value in .Find function VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below, but I have problem, I do not know how can I find row where SomeText is included in cell value. If my explanation is not clear example: SomeText = 1200 and want to get row index where cell value are as follow: 1200.0 and 1200.1. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Set cell1 = Selection.Find(What:=SomeText, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `xlWhole` to `xlPart`?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`

```
Set cell1 = Selection.Find(What:=SomeText, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```