# Find word in part of cell text, return column number: Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to implement a search function in a user form in Excel.

It should be able to take a word entered in a `TextBox` and go through every column in a specific row and search for the word. Then it should return the column where it was first discovered.

With my code below, it will look only at exact matches of the cell content. But if the cell value is for example: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sitamet" - I want to be able to search for "dolor".

Here is my code:

```
Dim rFind As Range     
With Range("D1:D100")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:=TextBox13.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rFind.Column
        MsgBox rFind.Row
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Just change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`...

Comment: Change `xlWhole` to `xlPart`.  (Which is easily googled by searching, for instance `excel vba find` and looking at the first result, and more easily found by using the macro recorder.)

Comment: @YowE3K you're getting sloppy, Wolfie beat you to it ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado - it took me a few seconds to ensure that that google search term would come up with the MSDN entry as the first result

Comment: You guys are genious :-) Thanks a lot !

Comment: @RuediSpring - next time, please do some simple research before posting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text which is part of cell value in .Find function VBA excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097383/find-text-which-is-part-of-cell-value-in-find-function-vba-excel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`

Docs: [Range.Find Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

---

You can also use an ampersand (`&`) to tidy up the returned result, it concatenates strings:

```
"Col: " & rFind.Column & ", Row: " & rFind.Row
' For example, gives the string "Col: 1, Row: 1" if found in A1
```

You say you want to search in "every column in a specific row" but you're looking in "the first 100 rows in a specific column"?! Not sure whether that's a typo or if your code is wrong. Either way, you could use the `Rows` or `Columns` objects. These should be used with *fully qualifying* your range, i.e. saying where it is.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1)      ' Range of entire first row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)   ' Range of entire first column
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A") ' Equivalent, range of entire first column
```

Rewrite:

```
Dim rFind As Range     
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("D")
    Set rFind = .Find(What:=TextBox13.Value, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Col: " & rFind.Column & ", Row: " & rFind.Row
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The section

```
LookAt:=xlWhole
```

should be

```
LookAt:=xlPart
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks as though you want to check for each word - this will do that:

```
Sub Check()
Dim vWords As Variant
Dim sCheck As String
Dim rFind As Range
Dim i As Long

sCheck = "Lorem ipsum, dolor sitamet" ' TextBox13.Value
sCheck = Replace(sCheck, ",", "")

vWords = Split(sCheck, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(vWords)
    With Range("D1:D100")
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=Trim(vWords(i)), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox rFind.Column
            MsgBox rFind.Row
        End If
        Set rFind = Nothing
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Wolfie you're right - I misunderstood what the OP was looking for (hence why i thought the need to set rFind to nothing per iteration)

Comment: Even if you're looping though, setting `rFind` to `Nothing` has no effect on your code, since it is changed on the next loop anyway. It doesn't matter or change the way the code works, just thought I'd try and help..

Comment: @Wolfie but it you didn't clear the rFind value, the `If Not rFind Is Nothing Then...` argument wouldn't be correct as it'd pick up the value form the previous iteration

Comment: That's what I'm trying to point out, it wouldn't! When you call `Set rFind = .Find(...)`, you have `rFind = Nothing` or `rFind = some range`. The `.Find` function will *always* change the value of `rFind` anyway. Maybe I'm not clear, see the docs ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)) - "This method returns Nothing if no match is found"

Answer (score -2):

Code updated: For all comments, 
1. xlPart added
2. Only one search performed,

Now if you could uprate me.

Simplest code to do it -
As per your range selected - Range("D1:D100"),  you are only finding row number where the value exists. In order to find the column number as well, expand your range.

This is it -

```
Sub find_code()
Dim add As String

On Error Resume Next
add = Range("D1:D100").Find(TextBox1.Text, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).AddressLocal

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Empty Search result", vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox Range(add).Row
MsgBox Range(add).Column

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, as it will crash if the text isn't found, because the find will return `Nothing` and you are requesting the `Row` of it. This is why the OP (correctly) used the `If Not rFind Is Nothing` logic.

Comment: Anyway, searching twice takes twice the time. Bad idea too!

Comment: And it will only use `xlPart` if that is what the OP had used on their previous `Find`.  (It is always best to specify whether the search is on `xlPart` or `xlWhole` because Excel remembers the last setting.)

Comment: Your edit is an improvement but not great. You're now potentially still causing an error, but ignoring it. This is worse than handling it properly like the OP has, as already mentioned. Also the "simplest code to do it" now looks more complicated than the original code, which only required 5 characters changing...